# Bulk Copying and Deleting in OneTransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In C# application I like to copy the table data from one server(SQLServer2000) to another server (SQLServer2005). I like to copy the data in single instance and delete the existing data in the SQL Server 2000 table. I need to do all this(Bulk copying and Deleting) in single transaction. How to achieve this?

Note: I am having two different sql server connections how to achieve this for single transaction

Answer (score 1):

To minimise the duration of the transaction, I always do this by bulk-copying to a *staging* table (same schema, but different name - no indexes etc), and then once all the data is at the server, do something like:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM FOO

INSERT FOO ...
SELECT ...
FROM FOO_STAGING

COMMIT TRAN

DELETE FROM FOO_STAGING
```

(the transaction could be either in the TSQL or on the connection via managed code, or via `TransactionScope`; the TSQL could be either as command-text, or as a SPROC)

Comment: Note that this solution gets you a snap shot transactionally but does not keep the read in the same transaction. This is almost certainly fine for all users and is worth the large perf benefit but it is worth noting.
Using a database with snapshot versioning should remove even that problem for the simple naive solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), although I've never tried doing this between a SQL2005 and a SQL2000 instance. On your SQL2005 instance:

```
sp_addlinkedserver Sql2000Server --Only need to do this once on the server

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (id, column) 
    SELECT id, column FROM Sql2000Server.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
DELETE FROM Sql2000Server.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
--etc...

COMMIT TRAN
```

See Microsoft books online for the syntax to add / remove linked servers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Further to the linked server suggestion, you can use SSIS as well, which would be my preferred method.